# Como eu faria para associar a tabela categoria a post com sequelize no NodeJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize-js

`O que eu quero fazer é obter uma tabela associativa com esse dois models, mas já tentei aqui de todo modo. Vi que tem que usar hasMany nos dois... Só não entendi onde eu colocaria isso. Seria no index?`

`Esse é o model do post`

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize')

const db = require('../db/conn')


const Post = db.define('Post', {

    nome:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false,

    },

    imagem_post:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },

    conteudo:{
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    },

    data_post:{
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
    

})


module.exports = Post
```

`Esse é o model da categoria`

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize')

const db = require('../db/conn')


const Categoria = db.define('Categoria', {

    nome:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
    },

    slug:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
    },


    data:{
        type:DataTypes.DATE,
        default:Date.now()


    }

})


module.exports = Categoria
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Se seu relacionamento é many-to-many, você precisa colocar os dois relacionamentos em abaixo da declaração de um dos models, exemplo:

```
Post.belongsToMany(Categoria, { through: 'post_categoria' })
Categoria.belongsToMany(Post, { through: 'post_categoria' })
```

Isso irá gerar uma tabela intermediária chamada post_categoria, que fará o relacionamento entre as entidades...

Comment: Opa, valeu! Eu tinha até feito isso, mas achei que não estava certo. Vou tentar aqui.